# How the result set passed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

I have a code that is working fine.
I just copied from the internet.

```
  db.transaction(function (tx, rs) {
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM persons", [],
         function(tx, rs) {
          callback(rs);
         },
         function(){alert("Failed to fetch data");});
   });
}
```

here, the `rs` specifies the result set. I just wanna know, whether any variable given as the second parameter ( `function(tx, rs)` ) will be taken as a result set?

If not, where will we get the result set of the given query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be writen as:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM persons", [],
         function(tx, rs) {
          callback(rs);
         },
         function(){alert("Failed to fetch data");});
   });
}
```

the `rs` parameter in your transaction-handler function doesn't actually exist. `db.transaction` creates a transaction object, and passes it into the handler function.  In this case, the handler is calling `executeSql` on the transaction object; the function that handles the results of `executeSql` *does* take a result-set parameter.

You don't set, pass, or create the `rs` parameter - it's created based on the results of the SQL query.